# Refreshing data table using dataTables and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a script that uses dataTables and Ajax to populate a table. What I am trying do do is when a new record is added to the underlying MySQLi table is to refresh the data in the on screen table view.

The script below is the code that inserts the new record, which works fine. How do I go about forcing the on screen data to refresh. I have looked at the number of post that talk about this and most of the answers talk about using dataTablesw "redraw" but I can't see how that works.

```
$("#insert_promotion").submit(function(event){
    var hotelid      = "<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>";
    var roomid       = $('#RoomID').val();
    var roomname         = $('#RoomName').val();
    var companyimage     = $('#company_image_1').val();
    var clientname       = $('#client_name').val();
    var fromdate         = $('#FromDate').val();
    var fromhours        = $('#RoomFromTimeH').val();
    var frommins         = $('#RoomFromTimeM').val();
    var todate           = $('#ToDate').val();
    var tohours          = $('#RoomToTimeH').val();
    var tomins           = $('#RoomToTimeM').val();
    var fromdisplaytimeh = $('#FromDisplayTimeH').val();
    var fromdisplaytimem = $('#FromDisplayTimeM').val();
    var displaytext      = $('#DisplayText').val();
    var lookupimage      = $('#NewBrowse').val();
    var roomlevel        = $('input[name=RoomLevel]:checked', '#insert_promotion').val()
    var displaylevel     = $('input[name=DisplayLevel]:checked', '#insert_promotion').val()
    var boardlevel       = $('input[name=BoardLevel]:checked', '#insert_promotion').val()
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('form')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("RoomID", roomid);
    formData.append("RoomName", roomname);
    formData.append("CompanyImage", companyimage);
    formData.append("ClientName", clientname);
    formData.append("RoomFromDate", fromdate);
    formData.append("RoomToDate", todate);
    formData.append("RoomFromTimeH", fromhours);
    formData.append("RoomFromTimeM", frommins);
    formData.append("RoomToTimeH", tohours);
    formData.append("RoomToTimeM", tomins);
    formData.append("FromDisplayTimeH", fromdisplaytimeh);
    formData.append("FromDisplayTimeM", fromdisplaytimem);
    formData.append("DisplayText", displaytext);
    formData.append("ClientImageName", lookupimage);
    formData.append("RoomLevel", roomlevel);
    formData.append("DisplayLevel", displaylevel);
    formData.append("BoardLevel", boardlevel);
    formData.append('image_field', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $(".progress-bar").animate({
      width: "100%"
    }, 2500);
    $.ajax({
      url:"insert_new_conference.php",
      data: formData,
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

    }).done(function(response){
      $('.progress-bar').attr('style', "width: 0%");
      $("#previewtext").html("");
      $("#NewPreview").html("");
      $('#insert_promotion')[0].reset();
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
      $('#FromDate').datepicker('setDate', null);
      $('#ToDate').datepicker('setDate', null);
      select_box = document.getElementById("RoomFromTimeH");
      select_box.selectedIndex = "00";
      select_box = document.getElementById("RoomFromTimeM");
      select_box.selectedIndex = "00";
      select_box = document.getElementById("RoomToTimeH");
      select_box.selectedIndex = -1;
      select_box = document.getElementById("RoomToTimeM");
      select_box.selectedIndex = -1;
      $('#RoomLevel_1').prop('checked', false);
      $('#RoomLevel_2').prop('checked', true);
      $('#RoomLevel_3').prop('checked', false);
      $('#RoomLevel_4').prop('checked', false);
      $('#DisplayLevel_1').prop('checked', false);
      $('#DisplayLevel_2').prop('checked', true);
      $('#DisplayLevel_3').prop('checked', false);
      $('#DisplayLevel_4').prop('checked', false);
      $('#BoardLevel_1').prop('checked', true);
      $('#BoardLevel_2').prop('checked', false);
      $("#ShowBar").hide();
      $('#add_data_modal').modal("hide");
      $.ajax({
        url: 'get_conf_bookings.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
          var len = response.length;
          $("#userTable tbody").html("");
          for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var recordid = response[i].RecordID;
            var roomid = response[i].RoomID;
            var roomname = response[i].RoomName;
            var clientimage = response[i].ClientImageNameAdminSmall;
            if(clientimage == null){
              var imagepath = '../images/no-image.png';
            } else {
              var imagepath = '../../../../conf/conf_images/adminsmall/'+ clientimage;
            }
            var rowspacer = '../images/row-spacer.png';
            var clientname = response[i].ClientName;
            var fromdate = response[i].RoomFromDateTime;
            var StartDate = response[i].RoomFromDate;
            var fromtime = response[i].RoomFromTime;
            var todate = response[i].RoomToDateTime;
            var totime = response[i].RoomToTime;
            var EndDate = response[i].RoomToDate;
            var enddate = todate +' '+totime;
            var startdate = fromdate +' '+fromtime;
            var startdate2 = response[i].StartDate +' '+fromtime;
            var enddate2 = response[i].EndDate +' '+totime;
                    var nowdate;
            var d = new Date();
            nowdate = (d.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))  + "-" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)  + " " + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
            var tr_str = "<tr class='TableText'>" +
            "<td style='color:#333;font-size:1em;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold;vertical-align:middle;'>" + roomname + "</td>" +
            "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;vertical-align:middle;'><img src='" + imagepath + "' /></td>" +
            "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;min-height:80px;vertical-align:middle;'><img src='" + rowspacer + "' /></td>" +
            "<td align='left'  style='color:#333;font-size:1em;white-space: nowrap;;vertical-align:middle;'>" + clientname + "</td>" +
            "<td align='left' style='color:#333;font-size:1em; white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:middle;'>" + fromdate + "</td>" +
            "<td align='cleft' style='color:#333;font-size:1em;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:middle;'>" + todate + "</td>"
            if(new Date(enddate2) < new Date(nowdate)){
              tr_str += "<td align='center' class='Complete'>Complete</td>";
            } else if (new Date(startdate2) > new Date(nowdate) && new Date(nowdate) < new Date(enddate2)) {
              tr_str += "<td align='center' class='Scheduled'>Scheduled</td>";
            } else {
              tr_str += "<td  class='Active'>Active</td>";
            }
            tr_str += "<td align='center'  style='color:#333;font-size:1em; margin-left:3px;margin-right:15px;vertical-align:middle;'><input type='button' name='edit' value='View' id=" + recordid + " class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block view_data_carousel'></td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
          }
        }
      });
      $("#userTable").ajax.reload(); //THIS LINE DOES NOT SEEM TO DO USING reload or redrawANYTHING
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try it !

```
$.ajax({
    url: your_get_url,
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function (data) {

    $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
         data: data
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I removed all the code from below "type:'GET' and replaced it with your code. I don't get any errors but the on screen data does not get updated/refreshed. Have I done this correctly?

Comment: is the data you are receiving in json format? make a console.log (data) to see

Comment: @ Issa Dicko very odd, I am now getting an error "DataTables warning: table id=userTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0." I am not sure what this is trying to tell me. If I skip over this error I then get 0: {RecordID: "46112", RoomID: "3", RoomName: "Baskerville  Suite", RoomZone: "1", RoomBooked: "1", …}
1: {RecordID: "45995", RoomID: "1", RoomName: "Bolton Suite", RoomZone: "1", RoomBooked: "1", …}
2: {RecordID: "46111", RoomID: "2", RoomName: "Watt  Suite", RoomZone: "1", RoomBooked: "1", …} those are the record I would expect

Comment: can I even see how you respond to the request in php

Comment: @ Issa Dicko This is the php response:[{"RecordID":"46112","RoomID":"3","RoomName":"Baskerville  Suite","RoomZone":"1","RoomBooked":"1"},{"RecordID":"45995","RoomID":"1","RoomName":"Bolton Suite","RoomZone":"1","RoomBooked":"1"},{"RecordID":"46113","RoomID":"4","RoomName":"Brindley  Suite","RoomZone":"1","RoomBooked":"1"}]. There are more fileds but far too many to post. In the php file I have this echo json_encode($return_arr);